# Powershell: Combining multiple commands in a foreach loop

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach, command

I need to run multiple commands over a foreach loop, but it seems as if I got stuck here...

What am I doing wrong and is it even possible?

Is there anyone who maybe can help me here?

See the code:

```
$WIP_Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $WIPPath -File | %{$_.FullName}

ForEach ($WIP_File in $WIP_Files) {
    
Get-Content $WIP_File -First 1 | % { $_.Split('\')[-1] } | % {$t += " $_"};[Regex]::Match($t, '(\w+)[^\w]*$').Groups[1].Value | % {$MeterNo += $_;"$_"}

    Get-Content $WIP_File -First 3 | Select -Last 1 | % { $_.Split('\')[-1] } | % {$t += " $_"};[Regex]::Match($t, '(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4})').Groups[1].Value | % {$GetDocDate += $_;"$_"}

    $DocDate = $GetDocDate.SubString(6,4) + $GetDocDate.SubString(0,2) + $GetDocDate.SubString(3,2)

    $FileName = $MeterNo + '_' + $DocDate + '.csv'

    Rename-Item -Path $WIP_File -NewName $WIPPath + '\' + $FileName
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it seems a if I got stuck here"? What are you trying to accomplish, what behavior are you expecting from this code, and how exactly does the observed behavior contradict those expectations when you actually run it?

Comment: Agreed^. There's just not enough information on what you're expecting. The only issue I see (*without knowing your full intent*) is, `$WIPPath + '\' + $FileName` should be placed inside a grouping construct such as `($WIPPath + '\' + $FileName)`. Otherwise `Rename-Item` will take it as separate tokens for its parameters/arguments.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback

I want to read multiple files to get the date and serial number specified inside these files. Then I want to build a name Serial Number + Date and rename original files with new names.

Answer (score 0):

I changed  `$WIPPath + '\' + $FileName` to `($WIPPath + '\' + $FileName)` as suggested.

And also changed `$t` respectively to `$M` and `$D`

See the code below that works for me at the moment any idea to do it in a better way?

```
    $WIPPath    = 'E:\Systems\Data\AMR\WIP\'
    cd $WIPPath
    $WIP_Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $WIPPath -File | %{$_.Name}
    ForEach ($WIP_File in $WIP_Files) {
        $M = '';
        
        $D = '';
        
        Get-Content $WIP_File -First 1 | % { $_.Split('\')[-1] } | % {$M += " $_"};[Regex]::Match($M, '(\w+)[^\w]*$').Groups[1].Value | Set-Variable -Name 'MeterNo' ;
        
        Get-Content $WIP_File -First 3 | Select -Last 1 | % { $_.Split('\')[-1] } | % {$D += " $_"};[Regex]::Match($D, '(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4})').Groups[1].Value | Set-Variable -Name 'GetDocDate';
        
        $FileName = $MeterNo + '_' + ($GetDocDate.SubString(6,4) + $GetDocDate.SubString(0,2) + $GetDocDate.SubString(3,2) + '.csv');
        
        Rename-Item -Path ($WIPPath+$WIP_File) -NewName ($FileName);
        
        Write-Host $GetDocDate ' - ' $WIPPath ' - ' $WIP_File  ' - ' $FileName;
    }
```